# How to use TCMalloc on Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: tcmalloc, google-cloud-ml-engine

How to use TCMalloc on Google Cloud ML Engine? Or apart from TCMalloc, is there any other way to solve memory leak issues on ML Engine?

Finalizing graph doesn't seem to help.

---

Memory utilization graph:
[image]

I've got out of memory error after training 73 epochs. Here is part of the training log:

> 11:26:33.707
>   Job failed.
>
> 11:26:20.949
>   Finished tearing down TensorFlow.
>
> 11:25:18.568
>   The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 247. To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs
>
> 11:25:07.785
>   Clean up finished.
>
> 11:25:07.785
>   Module completed; cleaning up.
>
> 11:25:07.783
>   Module raised an exception for failing to call a subprocess Command '['python', '-m', u'trainer.main', u'--data=gs://', u'--train_log_dir=gs://tfoutput/joboutput', u'--model=trainer.crisp_model', u'--num_threads=32', u'--memory_usage=0.8', u'--max_out_norm=1', u'--train_batch_size=64', u'--sample_size=112', u'--num_gpus=4', u'--allow_growth=True', u'--weight_loss_by_train_size=True', u'-x',  returned non-zero exit status -9.
>
> 11:23:08.853
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 11:18:18.474
>   epoch 58.0: accuracy = 0.9109
>
> 11:17:14.851
>   2017-05-17 10:17:14.851024: epoch 58, loss = 0.12, lr = 0.085500 (228.9 examples/sec; 0.280 sec/batch)
>
> 11:15:39.532
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 11:10:23.855
>   PoolAllocator: After 372618242 get requests, put_count=372618151 evicted_count=475000 eviction_rate=0.00127476 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00127518
>
> 11:05:32.928
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 10:59:26.006
>   epoch 57.0: accuracy = 0.8868
>
> 10:58:24.117
>   2017-05-17 09:58:24.117444: epoch 57, loss = 0.23, lr = 0.085750 (282.2 examples/sec; 0.227 sec/batch)
>
> 10:54:37.440
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 10:53:30.323
>   PoolAllocator: After 366350973 get requests, put_count=366350992 evicted_count=465000 eviction_rate=0.00126927 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.0012694
>
> 10:51:51.417
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 10:40:43.811
>   epoch 56.0: accuracy = 0.7897
>
> 10:39:41.308
>   2017-05-17 09:39:41.308624: epoch 56, loss = 0.06, lr = 0.086000 (273.8 examples/sec; 0.234 sec/batch)
>
> 10:38:14.522
>   PoolAllocator: After 360630699 get requests, put_count=360630659 evicted_count=455000 eviction_rate=0.00126168 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00126197
>
> 10:36:10.480
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 10:21:50.715
>   epoch 55.0: accuracy = 0.9175
>
> 10:20:51.801
>   PoolAllocator: After 354197216 get requests, put_count=354197255 evicted_count=445000 eviction_rate=0.00125636 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00125644
>
> 10:20:49.815
>   2017-05-17 09:20:49.815251: epoch 55, loss = 0.25, lr = 0.086250 (285.6 examples/sec; 0.224 sec/batch)
>
> 10:02:56.637
>   epoch 54.0: accuracy = 0.9191
>
> 10:01:57.367
>   2017-05-17 09:01:57.367369: epoch 54, loss = 0.09, lr = 0.086500 (256.5 examples/sec; 0.249 sec/batch)
>
> 10:01:42.365
>   PoolAllocator: After 347107694 get requests, put_count=347107646 evicted_count=435000 eviction_rate=0.00125321 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00125354
>
> 09:45:56.116
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:44:12.698
>   epoch 53.0: accuracy = 0.9039
>
> 09:43:09.888
>   2017-05-17 08:43:09.888202: epoch 53, loss = 0.10, lr = 0.086750 (307.0 examples/sec; 0.208 sec/batch)
>
> 09:41:48.672
>   PoolAllocator: After 339747205 get requests, put_count=339747210 evicted_count=425000 eviction_rate=0.00125093 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00125111
>
> 09:36:14.085
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:35:11.686
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:34:45.011
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:31:03.212
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:28:40.116
>   PoolAllocator: After 335014430 get requests, put_count=335014342 evicted_count=415000 eviction_rate=0.00123875 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00123921
>
> 09:27:38.374
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:25:23.913
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:25:16.065
>   epoch 52.0: accuracy = 0.9313
>
> 09:24:16.963
>   2017-05-17 08:24:16.962930: epoch 52, loss = 0.11, lr = 0.087000 (278.7 examples/sec; 0.230 sec/batch)
>
> 09:17:48.417
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 09:13:34.740
>   PoolAllocator: After 329380055 get requests, put_count=329379978 evicted_count=405000 eviction_rate=0.00122958 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00123001
>
> 09:06:09.948
>   update epoch 51.0: accuracy = 0.9357
>
> 09:06:09.948
>   epoch 51.0: accuracy = 0.9357
>
> 09:05:09.575
>   2017-05-17 08:05:09.575641: epoch 51, loss = 0.11, lr = 0.087250 (248.4 examples/sec; 0.258 sec/batch)
>
> 08:59:17.735
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 08:55:58.605
>   PoolAllocator: After 322904781 get requests, put_count=322904714 evicted_count=395000 eviction_rate=0.00122327 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00122368
>
> 08:48:46.322
>   PNG warning: Exceeded size limit while expanding chunk
>
> 08:47:27.936
>   epoch 50.0: accuracy = 0.9197
>
> 08:46:29.370
>   2017-05-17 07:46:29.370135: epoch 50, loss = 0.20, lr = 0.087500 (253.2 examples/sec; 0.253 sec/batch)

I've tried using TCMalloc for training on my local machine, there is still a memory leak but less than not using it.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your problem? In particular, what symptoms are  a you observing that lead you to believe you have a memory leak?

Comment: @rhaertel80 I just added training memory utilization graph and training logs. I got out of memory error after 73 epochs. I was using complex_model_m_gpu for the machine configuration. Training data: 257018 png images with size 128x128. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I directly answered the question about TCMalloc below, but obviously we need to find the memory leak. If your program doesn't exit when you use `finalize`, then your memory leak is probably somewhere else. Are you doing anything else on the master like performing evaluation? Any pointers to code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow uses [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) by default, and that is what is used on CloudML Engine as well:

> jemalloc is a general purpose malloc(3) implementation that emphasizes
>   fragmentation avoidance and scalable concurrency support.

So fragmentation is not likely the root cause of your memory issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've tried what mentioned in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3883/how-to-debug-a-memory-leak-in-tensorflow#t=201706080828378194766. After I changed to tcmalloc, the memory leak reduced to a very small amount comparing to jemalloc.

Comment: But I cannot use tcmalloc on Google Cloud ML Engine, so the memory leak is still a problem for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44412820/1399222. We're currently investigating.